# Combine several filters into one filter() with django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) app. There is however one problem I do not know how to solve. It's almost exactly the same thing as is described in django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

I want to make a query where I select all Blogs that has an entry with **both** "Lennon" in headline **and** was published in 2008, eg.:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', 
    entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

Not to select Blogs that has an entry with "Lennon" in headline and another entry (possibly the same) that was published in 2008:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(
    entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

However, if I set up Filter such that there are two fields (nevermind __contains x __exact, just an example):

```
class BlogFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    entry__headline = django_filters.CharFilter()
    entry__pub_date = django_filters.CharFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['entry__headline', 'entry__pub_date', ]
```

django-filter will generete the latter:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__exact='Lennon').filter(
    entry__pub_date__exact=2008)
```

Is there a way to combine both filters into a single filter field?

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this old thread, but
`Foo.objects.filter(foo="bar").filter(qux="quux")`
actually is the same as
`Foo.objects.filter(foo="bar", qux="quux")`
Multiple keyword arguments and consequent filters are "AND"ed together. To create "OR" filters, you have to use `Q` objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: @cvk hi, according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships (both dev and 1.2 version) using two chained filters produces "select all blogs that contain an entry with "Lennon" in the headline as well as an entry that was published in 2008" but when using a single one with comma it produces "select all blogs that contain entries with both "Lennon" in the headline and that were published in 2008 (the same entry satisfying both conditions)". Which is a huge difference. I have not yet found a way to do this using django-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I came with a solution. It is not possible to do using the regular django-filters, so I extended it a bit. Could've been improved, this is quick-n-dirty solution.

1st added a custom "grouped" field to django_filters.Filter and a filter_grouped method (almost copy of filter method)

```
class Filter(object):

    def __init__(self, name=None, label=None, widget=None, action=None,
        lookup_type='exact', required=False, grouped=False, **kwargs):
        (...)
        self.grouped = grouped

    def filter_grouped(self, qs, value):
        if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            lookup = str(value[1])
            if not lookup:
                lookup = 'exact' # we fallback to exact if no choice for lookup is provided
            value = value[0]
        else:
            lookup = self.lookup_type
        if value:
            return {'%s__%s' % (self.name, lookup): value}
        return {}
```

the only difference is that instead of creating a filter on query set, it returns a dictionary.

2nd updated BaseFilterSet qs method/property:

```
class BaseFilterSet(object):
    (...)
    @property
    def qs(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_qs'):
            qs = self.queryset.all()
            grouped_dict = {}
            for name, filter_ in self.filters.iteritems():
                try:
                    if self.is_bound:
                        data = self.form[name].data
                    else:
                        data = self.form.initial.get(name, self.form[name].field.initial)
                    val = self.form.fields[name].clean(data)
                    if filter_.grouped:
                        grouped_dict.update(filter_.filter_grouped(qs, val))
                    else:
                        qs = filter_.filter(qs, val)
                except forms.ValidationError:
                    pass

            if grouped_dict:
                qs = qs.filter(**grouped_dict)

        (...)
    return self._qs
```

The trick is to store all "grouped" filters in a dictionary and then use them all as a single filter.

The filter will look something like this then:

```
class BlogFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    entry__headline = django_filters.CharFilter(grouped=True)
    entry__pub_date = django_filters.CharFilter(grouped=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['entry__headline', 'entry__pub_date', ]
```